# Call to undefined method JAdminCssMenu::load()

Tags: joomla, upgrade, joomla3.0

I have updated joomla version from 3.6.5 to 3.7 joomla latest version.
Now I am getting fatal error on site backend :

Fatal error: Call to undefined method JAdminCssMenu::load() in /public_html/administrator/modules/mod_menu/mod_menu.php on line 25

Can anyone please provide me solution to get it fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced mod_menu complete Directory/Files with old one (3.6.5) and its working now.

Comment: I am having same problem.  Deleted contents of administrator/modules/mod_menu.php and then uploaded folder from Joomla 3.6.5 and still having an issue.  Were there any other steps you took?

Comment: Please rename the latest mod_menu folder and upload the old mod_menu(3.6.5). I have done same process and its working.

Comment: I found an odd Admin Hider plugin that must have been installed before I took over project.  When opening, all the options were missing, so I am thinking it wasn't compatible with newer Joomla.  Really wish I had found that quicker.

Answer (score 1):

The temp fix does work, (uncomment line 25). However I found it was a component that was causing the error, SP Page Builder, once uninstalled, all worked fine :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but you don't need to uninstall SPPageBuilder, just go to yoursite.co.uk/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&view=modules, filter by Administrator modules and unpublish the one called "SP Page Builder Admin Menu".

Answer (score 0):

I have also received the same error on a couple sites so far after updating. I added a php override to my htaccess file to bring the sites back online. I added the following to the rewrite section of my htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

This increases the memory to 128MB. Not the best way to fix the issue, but it works right now. I don't know if this issue is related to the 3.7 upgrade or not, but it's awfully coincidental that 2 of my sites, and now coming across this post happened after upgrading. I wonder if there is a bug in the new Joomla version, or if it requires more memory now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not working at my end.. I have updated memory limit on both php.ini and htaccess but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is faced by many who used `JSN Poweradmin`. You need to uninstall it to run your Joomla site or you can simply comment out or delete this line on line no 25

```
//$menu->load($params, $enabled);
```

in the file `/administrator/modules/mod_menu/mod_menu.php`.

Comment: I am not using JSN Poweradmin and if get comment out this line then back end menu will get disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **JSN Poweradmin** and you tried to install **SP Page Builder**, Just go to this directory:

administrator\modules

and delete this folder: **mod_sppagebuilder_admin_menu**

Now Joomla Admin panel would work OK and also **SP Page Builder** component is ready to use.